# Import *.xml into FileMaker Pro

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I´m new in FileMaker, and I have to import a *.xml file into it. I have read the help on the FileMaker homepage and looked at the example *.xml and *.xlst-files.

Unfortunately I have no experience with xslt. How can I tackle this?

Here is the example *.xml:

```
<ORDER_HEADER>
    <ORDER_INFO>
      <ORDER_ID>1860</ORDER_ID>
      <ORDER_DATE>2012-11-27</ORDER_DATE>
      <ORDER_PARTIES>
        <BUYER_PARTY>
          <PARTY>
            <PARTY_ID type="supplier_specific">999999</PARTY_ID>
            <ADDRESS>
              <NAME>Martin</NAME>
              <STREET>A-Street</STREET>
            </ADDRESS>
          </PARTY>
        </BUYER_PARTY>
        <SUPPLIER_PARTY>
          <PARTY>
            <PARTY_ID type="buyer_specific">1984</PARTY_ID>
            <ADDRESS>
              <NAME>GmbH</NAME>
              <STREET>B-Street</STREET>
            </ADDRESS>
          </PARTY>
        </SUPPLIER_PARTY>
        <INVOICE_PARTY>
          <PARTY>
            <PARTY_ID type="supplier_specific">999999</PARTY_ID>
            <ADDRESS>
              <NAME>AG</NAME>
              <STREET>C-Street</STREET>
            </ADDRESS>
          </PARTY>
        </INVOICE_PARTY>
        <SHIPMENT_PARTIES>
          <DELIVERY_PARTY>
            <PARTY>
              <ADDRESS>
                <NAME>Stadt</NAME>...</
                <NAME2>...</NAME2>
                <STREET>D-Street</STREET>
              </ADDRESS>
            </PARTY>
          </DELIVERY_PARTY>
        </SHIPMENT_PARTIES>
      </ORDER_PARTIES>
      <PRICE_CURRENCY>EUR</PRICE_CURRENCY>
      <TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS>...</TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS>
      <REMARK type="order">...</REMARK>
    </ORDER_INFO>
  </ORDER_HEADER>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know XSLT, then the only tip is to learn it. Look around for other questions in FileMaker/XML categories; there were some pretty detailed examples, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12134342/478521).

Answer (score -1):

You are in luck:

```
File > Import Records > XML Data Source
```

Comment: This won't work; the XML must be the special FileMaker XML (`FMPXMLRESULT`), while the OP has different XML and needs to transform it into `FMPXMPLRESULT` first.

Comment: Huh. I never used it, but always thought "import xml" would handle ... well ... normal xml. Sigh. FileMaker.