# In XSLT for MODS XML to FilemakerPro conversion, how treat a mod with a parameter?

Tags: xslt, xpath, filemaker, xmlconvert

Referring to query [XSLT to translate Zotero xml output to FMPXMLRESULT xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132470/xslt-to-translate-zotero-xml-output-to-fmpxmlresult-xml), how in the XSLT do I refer to a mod such as:

```
<genre authority="marcgt"> book </genre>
```

(There are multiple mods beginning `genre authority`, each with a different parameter. So what is the syntax in the XSLT for that? I tried the following, but Filemaker says there's a syntax error.

```
<COL>
   <DATA>
      <xsl:value-of select="mod:genre authority=""marcgt""" />
   </DATA>
 </COL>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select is looking for a node to pick, it seems like you are trying to point it to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="mod:genre[@authority='marcgt']" />
```

Comment: That did it -- thanks, @AlwaysWrong (a misnomer at least here)! What I didn't know how to do was the use of the `[`...`]` construction and then the use in it of single quotes, rather than doubled double-quotes or escaped quotes, or some other variant. It's hard, as I'm not an XML programmer and am rather stumbling in the dark in order to move a bibliography from Zotero (obtained from Library of Congress database information) into FileMaker Pro, where I can massage it and -- ultimately -- export it for use in Bento.